# .htaccess Redirect images folder to another domain

Tags: php, .htaccess

ok so i have 2 domains 
site1.com/images/ (all images)

and I need to redirect the imgages link site1.com/images/   to site2.com/images/ so that when 
and when exp. site1.com/images/i.jpg is called it will look at site2.com/images/1.jpg and will find it.
.this is basic duplicate of the site and i don't want to move images back and forward.

Answer (score 5):

Put in your .htaccess on site1.com

```
Redirect permanent /images http://sites2.com/images
```

Answer (score 2):

If the websites are on the same server and running under the same user, you could use symbolic links between both websites.

E.g., create a symlink to `/home/site2/public_html/images` in `/home/site1/public_html/images`. Another option is using the [Apache's `Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive:

```
Alias /images /home/site2/public_html/images
```

Put this in the vhost config of `site1`.

Using redirection on Apache:

```
RedirectPermanent /images http://site2.example.com/images
```

The best way would probably fixing the HTML code pointing to one domain. If you cannot decide which domain should get the static content, create a subdomain (or even a different domain) to store the files.